# Wilson's theorem and fractions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> What is the remainder of $m$ satisfying $$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} +\dots+\frac{1}{33}=\frac{m}{33!}$$ upon division by $17$?

The factorial here hints me towards Wilson's theorem, but I cannot seem to get this in any way to the form such that I could use it. How should I go about this?

Comment: I reckon that's equivalent to $$\frac{17}1+\frac{17}2+\cdots+\frac{17}{16}+1+\frac{17}{18}+\cdots+\frac{17}{33}=\frac{m}{16!\times 18\times19\times\cdots\times 33}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$m=\frac{33!}{1}+\frac{33!}{2}+\cdots+\frac{33!}{33}$$

And we have to find the remainder when $m$ is divided by $17$.

Note that out of all the above terms, all terms except $\dfrac{33!}{17}$ are divsible by $17$. Thus $m\equiv \frac{33!}{17} \pmod{17}$.

But we have $$\begin{aligned}\frac{33!}{17}&=33\times 32\times \cdots \times 18 \times 16\times \cdots \times 1 \\&\equiv (-1)\times (-2)\times\cdots\times (-16)\times16\times\cdots \times1 \pmod{17} \\ &\equiv (16!)^2\pmod{17}\end{aligned}$$

Now from [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=exactly%20when%20n%20is%20a,1%20is%20divisible%20by%20n.), we have $16!\equiv -1\pmod{17} \implies (16!)^2\equiv 1 \pmod{17}$

Thus $m\equiv \boxed{1} \pmod{17}$

Comment: How would one know that $\frac{33!}{17}$ isn't divisible by $17$? I see that the initial $17$ from the numerator cancels with the denominator, but isn't there any $17$ that could be factored from the leftover $33!$?

Comment: @Daniel The factorial $33!$ is the product of all numbers from $1$ to $33$. Which of those is a multiple of $17$? Remember also that $17$ is a prime number. So how many times will $17$ occur in the prime factorization of $33!$ and $33!/17$?

Comment: @Daniel , you might want to write the expansion of $33!$, (after knowing the definition of factorial) and see for yourself that how many times $17$ appears in it.